# Hiding columns in ASP.Net Datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

My `DataGrid` is something like this:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="tasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="task-list-header"/>
    <ItemStyle  CssClass="task-list-row"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name"
                         HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                         HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Description"
                         HeaderStyle-Width="250px"
                         HeaderText="Description"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IsComplete"
                         HeaderStyle-Width="125px"
                         HeaderText="Is Complete"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderStyle Width="75px"/>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink1" runat="server"
                    NavigateUrl='<%# ModuleContext.EditUrl("TaskId", Eval("TaskId").ToString(), "EditTask") %>'
                    Text="Edit"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderStyle Width="75px"/>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskId") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

This is basically a list of Task with Last 2 columns as `Edit` and `Delete`. I am using DNN8. I want to hide the `Edit` and `Delete` links if the user is not logged in as Superuser. How can I do that? I also tried the property `OnAutoBinding` but no luck.

Thanks, in advance for the help.

Comment: You can use Visible="false" on your linkbutton and when the user is logged in, change the visibility.

Comment: Yes, I know I can use the Visible property of the Datagrid. But I Want to use it dynamically with a codition like `(userInfo.IsSuperUser?visible = true:Visible=false)`

Answer (score 0):

You can you like this

```
e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Visible = false;
```